# How can I show bigger images on my wordpress page?

Tags: wordpress, image, size, image-resizing

This is a page of my blog https://desandre.odns.fr/lemadame/portfolio-work/carole-nicolas (ssl is not active so you should clicked on advanced and then continue).
The theme I use shows images 1110px wide but I would like to show bigger pictures like here for example: https://damiendesandre.myportfolio.com/carole-et-nicolas It seems much better.

How can I get this result ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have any builder plugin then you have to add image only in row component and you will get the 80% width of image based on screen resolution.